# A plane curve of degree 3 with three singular points

Tags: projective-space, local-rings, tangent-spaces

I have tried to solve the question below from Igor R. Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry I

> Prove that if a plane curve of degree 3 has three singular points then it breaks up as a union of 3 lines.

I tried to solve this using the dimension of the tangent space of this plane curve since the singular points have a higher dimension than the minimum dimension of the tangent space of the curve. I connected two of three singular points to make lines. However, I do not know how to go further from here.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea that you need to connect the singular points by lines. If you can show that the plane curve must contain each of these 3 lines, then because the degree of the curve is 3, the polynomial for the curve must decompose as the product of 3 linear terms. Then the plane curve is just the union of those 3 lines.

Do you think you can show that the line connecting a pair of the singular points is contained in the plane curve?